# iOS and OpenCV: how to initialise CvVideoCamera object to reflect UIImage size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, uiimage

This is the code that I use to initialise the **CvVideoCamera** feed into the UIImage view object in my ViewController. How can I make so that the camera adjusts to the size of the UIImageView?

**As it is now the camera is slightly smaller when the view first loads first and gets bigger only when I rotate the screen**.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView];
    self.videoCamera.delegate = self;

    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    self.videoCamera.defaultFPS = 30;
    self.videoCamera.rotateVideo = true;
    self.videoCamera.grayscaleMode = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you initialise the camera as follows.

```
    self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] init];
```

then in your `processImage:(cv::Mat &)image` method you should set the image to the UIImageView explicitly using GCD. Also make sure you convert it from BGR to RGB before converting to a UIImage using `cvtColor` as below

```
    Mat RGB;
    cvtColor(image, RGB, CV_BGR2RGB);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.capturePreview.image = [UIImage UIImageFromCVMat:RGB];
    });
```

In this case the `self.capturePreview` is an instance of UIImageView. The critical component you are then missing is to make sure in your `viewDidLoad()` method you add the line `self.capturePreview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;`

The default mode for UIImageView's are `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` and as a consequence your image is effectively being captured by the camera and clipped.

Hope it helps!